# Is it safe to delete Druid's folder var/tmp

Tags: storage, druid

I am testing batch data ingestion in [Druid](http://druid.io). Currently in my installation there is a folder `$DRUID/var/tmp` which grew to almost 1TB (terabyte, yes) now. And `$DRUID/var/druid` is mere 350GB. Is it safe to delete that `$DRUID/var/tmp` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was answered in Druid user group, it is safe to delete the contents of the `tmp` folder while no ingestion task is running.